# Cryptic question

Tags: cipher

I am stuck on this question which a friend gave me. Please help guys. The question is:

The version tells it all
drbocryvn
uqlwzq
cpluuh

Comment: I hear that the community does not respond well to these types of questions.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please check out [Code Puzzles - What not to do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) over on meta. It gives guidelines for code puzzles and explains why questions like this are generally unsolvable without more hints (and also not *fun* to solve). Also, please check tag wikis before using the tags - [cryptic-clues] are a specific type of crossword clue.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Hey that's exactly what I would say.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, if the story about your friend is true, maybe this means something to you.

> The first word is "threshold" rotated 16 times.
>  The second word is "midori" rotated 18 times.
>  The third word is "vienna" rotated 19 times.

Visit rot13.com if you don't know what this means.

Comment: Based on the lead in sentence "The version tells it all", these three words are [codenames for versions of Microsoft operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames).